# Tensorflow Keras sigmoid activation in functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to perform sigmoid activation using the functional API, such as:

```
next_layer = tf.keras.activations.sigmoid(previous_layer)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a 
TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: 
Tensor("Relu:0", shape=(?, 200), dtype=float32, device=/device:GPU:0)
```

I can, however, easily call e.g.,

```
next_layer = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(previous_layer)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include your network model?

Comment: I think Keras activation functions are not meant to be used directly, but rather passed as parameters to layers. LeakyReLU should probably be an activation function too, but since it has a parameter to it (`alpha`) it is slightly different to other activation functions.

Comment: If you just really want to pass the output of one layer through a sigmoid you can use a `Lambda` layer, there you can use `tf.keras.activations.sigmoid`, `tf.keras.backend.sigmoid`, `tf.nn.sigmoid` or `tf.math.sigmoid` (which are all the same thing).

Comment: @jdehesa Could you include an example please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this:

```
next_layer = tf.keras.layers.Activation(activation='sigmoid')(previous_layer)
```

You can't call activation functions directly on Keras symbolic tensors.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was after.